# Linux exec with unprivileged user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service

I have a `/ect/init/app.conf` file that looks something like...

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

chdir /home/richie/application
exec app >> /var/log/app.log 2>&1
```

How can I change the exec line to run as an unprivileged user?

Comment: use sudo user. you need to log in that user and program it in.

Comment: Not a programming question.... off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec sudo -u username app > /var/log/app.log 2>&1`